# While sending EOS to GStreamer Pipeline the live streaming and feed buffer data getting missing/Lost/Deleted

Tags: java, android, c++, gstreamer

I'm currently facing an issue with my GStreamer setup where I'm attempting to record live feed data for a fixed duration, let's say 10 minutes. However, I've observed that in scenarios with low internet connectivity, the recorded data duration varies significantly and is often incomplete. While under optimal conditions, the recording captures the full 10-minute duration, during periods of poor internet connectivity, the recorded data may only span 5 minutes, 6 minutes, or even as short as 3 minutes. This inconsistency becomes more pronounced as the recording time increases.

In the first pipeline, I'm hosting the data on TCP Port 5001 and 5002 for recording locally and sending same feed to ant media server, and in the second pipeline, I'm reading the data from 5001 port and recording it into an MP4 file locally on the device. And in the third pipeline reading data and sending live feed onto ant media server.

**Here's a simplified version of my first pipeline:**

```
`rtspsrc location=" + CameraSettingParameter.getRtspURL() + " latency=100 udp-reconnect=1 " +
"timeout=5000000 wait-for-keyframe=1 name=rtspSrc ! " +
"rtpjitterbuffer drop-on-latency=true " +
"latency=100 ! parsebin " +
"sink-caps=\"video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,stream-format=byte-stream\" ! " +
"tee name=t t. ! queue ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink name=video-sink sync=true " +
"t. ! queue ! tcpserversink port=5002 sync=true "+
"t. ! queue ! valve name=streamvalve drop=false ! tcpserversink port=5001 sync=false";`
```

**And here's the second pipeline:**

```
`tcpclientsrc port=5001 ! " +
(CameraSettingParameter.getDecoder().equals("H264") ? " h264parse ! avdec_h264" : "h265parse ! avdec_h265") +
" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=" + vw + ",height=" + vh + " ! queue ! x264enc  ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink sync=false location=" + videoFileName + " buffer-mode=2 buffer-time=120000000";
`
```

**And here's the Third pipeline:**

```
`
 "tcpclientsrc  port=5002 ! " +
                "capsfilter caps=\"video/x-h265, " +
                "media=(string)video," +
                "clock-rate=(int)90000, " +
                "width=(int)1280, " +
                "height=(int)720," +
                "framerate=30/1, " +
                "payload=(int)96, " +
                "encoding-name=(string)H265, " +
                "stream-format=(string)byte-stream\" ! " +
                "queue " +
                "max-size-buffers=600 " +
                "max-size-time=90000000000 ! " +
                "decodebin ! " +
                "videoconvert ! " +
                "videoscale ! " +
                "videorate ! " +
                "video/x-raw," +
                "width="+ videoWidth +","+//1280," +
                "height="+ videoHeight+","+ //720," +
                "framerate="+String.valueOf(CameraSettingParameter.getFrameRate())+"/1 ! " +
                "x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast " +
                "tune=zerolatency ! " +
                "h264parse ! " +
                "flvmux streamable=true ! " +
                "rtmpsink location=\""+ streamingServerUrl +" live=true\" sync=false";
`
```

While this setup works well under stable network conditions, I'm encountering issues when there are fluctuations in the network connectivity. Sometimes, the data received on TCP Port 5001 is incomplete or delayed, leading to gaps or inconsistencies in the recorded video file.

I'm seeking guidance on how to optimize these pipelines or implement error handling mechanisms to ensure reliable and consistent recording of live video feed, especially in scenarios with variable network conditions.

**My device config :**
Android 9
4GB RAM / 2-4GB ROM

**My conclusion :** 1) Under fluctuating internet connectivity, the recording is incomplete or not full.** OR** 2) The first pipeline fails to send data over TCP port 5001, resulting in an incomplete or short live video recording. This occurs especially when attempting to send an EOS (End of Stream) signal on the Second pipeline, as it may not contain any data due to connectivity issues.